# onChange specify tab google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way of specify the tab of a spreadsheet when using onChange trigger.

I have a function that is running fine but since there are references and things change in several tabs in my spreadsheet the function fires several times. I tried something like this but it only works for edit and not change.

```
function Button(e) {
  // Get the sheet where the data is, in sheet 'Notif Inv'
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'Trigger') {

listFolers();
 }

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(sec*1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

      FolderMaker();
      createFoldersTasks_();
      createFolderByTask_();
      createFolders_();
      createFolderInFolder_();
      isFolderInFolder_();
 
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the onChange trigger? Is the trigger function running? Why do you want an onChange instead of an onEdit, what kind of changes do you want to track?

Comment: I am using the onChange trigger instead of onEdit because I have data coming in from another source and I don't physically change something. It basically detect when a new value is being added to a cell. The only way I managed to make the function fire is to use an onChange trigger. If you have any other ideas I would be happy to hear them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger once (onChange is an installable trigger, not onEdit)

Then you will get the name of the sheet where you are changing something. You can then compare to your setting.

```
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  if(isTrigger('button')) {return}
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('button')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
function isTrigger(funcName) {
  var r=false;
  if(funcName) {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++) {allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction())}
    if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1) {r=true}
  }
  return r;
}
function button(e){
  Browser.msgBox(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName())
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful. I ran it and it gives me the message that only one sheet is chaning so I am not sure why it is firing double, I will have to go back and see why it is making trouble.

Comment: if it fires double, go to your script editor interface, click on the clock and erase one of the two triggers. You only have to do createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger one time

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much it is all working now :)